# Are edit summaries only intended for the benefit of the reviewers?

Tags: discussion

I've come across several edits by >2000 users which contain no edit summary (just the automatically inserted "deleted xx characters in body").

Should I assume that edit summaries are not regarded useful when the edits don't need to be approved?

[This question and its answers/comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3502/what-to-do-about-good-suggested-edits-with-very-bad-summaries) seem to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The whole world can see our edit summaries.

They are not *just* for the benefit of reviewers. They're not even just for reviewers and others who might question if an edit should be kept or partially reverted / completely rolled back. *They are for anyone reading the revision history.*

Edit summaries appear in every post's edit history, "for all time." They are [viewable by anyone](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3502/what-to-do-about-good-suggested-edits-with-very-bad-summaries#comment5136_3504) who can view the post. Edit histories are not indexed by search engines, but any person can look at them.

For example, I improved the appearance of an ordered list in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56220/how-to-replace-libreoffice-with-openoffice/56264#56264) with the edit summary `improved formatting`. Now suppose someone clicks the link to view the post's revision history:

[image: Screenshot showing mouse over link to revision history.]

Then they get this page, which shows:

[image: Revisions page, showing edit summary.]

#### Edit summaries are useful even when an edit doesn't require approval.

This does not *necessarily* mean that submitting a blank edit summary is universally bad. Sometimes an edit is simple, the justification is easy and non-controversial, and it speaks for itself more clearly than a summary. In these situations, it is *acceptable* to submit a blank edit summary, because the system automatically adds [syntax-based edit summaries](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3502/what-to-do-about-good-suggested-edits-with-very-bad-summaries#comment5157_3508) when none is provided. (Like `edited title`, `edited tags`, and `removed 13 characters from body`.)

However, [as Oli says](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6248/22949), **it is never wrong to provide an edit summary**. (Unless the edit summary is wrong. Or provides no information. Like the `improved post` edit summaries I [complained about there](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3502/what-to-do-about-good-suggested-edits-with-very-bad-summaries).)

Answer (score 7):

I would say edit summaries are there to justify an edit that may not be completely obvious. *Most* edits we do are formatting or language fixes so they are obvious. They don't need a summary written out for them.

But occasionally I'll do an edit that changes the meaning of something, either because a fact has changed in time or it's just not quite correct. In these cases it's important to provide a summary, not only because it might get reviewed but because the author (even if that's you) might want to review the edit at some point in the future. A summary provides a log.

If you're unsure, consider this the other way: edit summaries are never considered un-useful; providing a summary can never hurt.