# edit suggestions: problem with meaningless comments

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I am in a dilemma:

There is one user who contributes (very) good edit suggestion but the comments are almost always the same: *improved formatting*, even if he did a lot more.

- I do want to get that user to formulate more meaningful comments (to make it easier for reviewers **and** to provide a useful edit history)
- I flagged one of those edited posts for moderator intervention but was told

  > if users' edit summaries can use improvement, you can let users know yourself that they may wish to use better edit summaries - it's not something that we really need to do anything for as mods if it's just a 'poor quality edit summary' thing.
- I do **not** want to reject those good edits just because of bad comments (I did it once with a polite request but apparently without success)
- I already posted a comment on a post edited by him - not sure if that gets to his inbox, though.

So: provided I am not just being silly in this regard (please tell me if you think I am): How can we educate editors to provide meaningful comments?

I **maintain**: [This question by Eliah Kagan](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3502/what-to-do-about-good-suggested-edits-with-very-bad-summaries) is mainly about what action (approve/reject) to take. I already know that I don't want to reject good edits. I am asking here about a way to contact/educate the contributor. So this is IMO not a duplicate.

<sub>I intentionally left out names, because I think this issue is more about a general "problem" than about single personalities.</sub>

Comment: Note that most people never see the reject messages on their suggested edits. They are kind of buried in your profile page. Have you tried leaving a comment on one of their posts instead?

Comment: @terdon, you mean a comment on just any "real" post of that person? I didn't think of this, I commented on one post edited by him, but I am not sure if that will make it to his inbox.

Comment: @guntbert if you approve the edit, you can leave a (pinged) comment on the edited post.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, you mean after having accepted the edit I revisit the post and address a comment at him?

Comment: @guntbert exactly, then the comment is connected to the edit, and he or she will be pinged to the edited post.

Comment: Yes, editors can be pinged by comments left on a post they've edited. But yes you could also leave a comment on any of their posts.

Answer (score -1):

My friend , When I am new to Ask Ubuntu , I should give a comment with respect to my edit and which regards what I did to the post to make it right but after a while I have got a privilege and after that I dont need to give any comment after editing any post. our system will take my edits automatically with out any comments.

So may be , comments were introduced for a different purpose like **saving reviewers time** , and some users used to do edits continuously one after one and they wont have patience to take care of comment field also with well oxford English as their main focus on post but not on comment.

If you do some 20-30 edits in a day may be you will understand it , why commenting is so irritating. so they let chrome auto filling feature to fill comment field.:P

Comment: By the time you are allowed to edit without explanation, your edits do not pass the reviewers anymore. I don't think that's what the question is about. He mentions "*I don't want to reject them*".

Comment: yeah but if you do 20-30 edits everyday , you think you will have enough patience to give good comments ? I mean seriously after understanding whats the op would like to say and trying to place in very understandable  manner ,itisnt easy right. what I want to say , we should give exception these comments.

Comment: If somebody is not able to think about what they are doing and to give a short description they maybe should reduce the amount of edit suggestions per day.

Comment: @guntbert I have done 10 edits in a single post and you want me to explain those 10 edits why I did in comment ? May be you are talking about the process that every one should follow but I am talking about what  actually will happen in common user mind while he is typing in comment field.

Comment: It looks like you don't remember any more how it was when you had to **suggest** edits :-) -- What I did (and still do): I categorize (eg: formatting, spelling, grammar, factual corrections should be mentioned expressively) - so even those "10 edits" result in a comprehensible comment.

Comment: @guntbert , yes as a practical person I agree with you. we are different people with different mindsets.